# How does the penalty for multiple actions work?

Tags: multiattack, mini-six

On page 6, the *Mini Six* rules state:

> ###### Multiple Actions
>
> Characters may attempt to do more than one thing on a turn by withholding one die from every action they attempt for each action beyond the first. For instance, if a character tries to shoot twice, he will subtract one die from each attempt.

There seems to be no *penalty* for taking multiple actions – just a lower chance of succeeding. Does this mean that every turn, **the optimal play is to take multiple actions till you're out of dice?** Is sportsmanship the only thing stopping players from doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The die penalty applies to every action on that turn,** including ones taken before later actions – not just on the extra actions and ones taken thereafter. The number of actions you'll take thus has to be declared in advance.

Technically, the rulebook states that everyone should declare their actions at the start of the turn – before any characters act at all, and only after that start resolving them. According to Mini Six's co-creator,  however, [it's likely that most people don't play that way.](https://www.reddit.com/r/minisix/comments/8ceaxx/a_few_clarifications_on_combat/dxz7qkd/) He also mentions that **if a player wants to take an undeclared extra action after already rolling,** a GM may choose to let the player do so with extra dice penalties on that roll (**one extra die penalty per action earlier in the turn** – for example, the second action may be -2D if the first action was taken without penalty).